# Heat Trap for bottom mounted cold water connection

Tags: plumbing, water-heater

I am getting a Rheem HP Water Heater XE80T10HS45U0 and the installation mentions adding a 6in minimum heat trap before the cold water inlet. If my cold water connection is coming from the ceiling in the room and then down to the inlet, should I do a J shape before connecting to the cold water inlet? Is this going to be enough? or should I use one of those inline heat traps as well?

[image]

Comment: I cannot believe that a $2,500 water heater is not fitted with a heat trap nipple.

Comment: Surprising, isn't it? It's a weird omission on these units.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[They walk through a bit of this in their installer training](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eilf3gBT6s4&t=2945s). Your heat trap just needs to be a six inch hard pipe riser located before any flexible connection to the water heater. They also indicate that the flexible connection should not be PEX. There's a diagram in the manual which is quite similar to the one in the training video.

Comment: This is very useful thank you! Yeah it does say they actually want a hard pipe connection at the water inlet for first 18in, interesting. Thanks again